# MVC Unobtrusive custom rule only works in one form on client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I built a custom validation rule for one particular field on my MVC 5 app.  It works great on the edit form, but when validating that same field on the "create' form, <s>the client side validation does not fire</s>  - The client side validation is triggered, but on the create form it shows as valid, even though I can see it is not.  So no message is shown.

Both forms use the same model.
The scripts are added in the _layout page so both views have all the scripts.
Both views have the exact same razor code including the ValidationMessageFor()

When the form gets to the controller, the model is not valid due to the custom error.  So the validation is working on the server side, but not the client.  I can't find anything that would make it work in one form but not the other.

Here is my code:

Custom attribute:

```
public class AtLeastOneRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public string OtherPropertyNames;

    public AtLeastOneRequiredAttribute(string otherPropertyNames)
    {
        OtherPropertyNames = otherPropertyNames;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string[] propertyNames = OtherPropertyNames.Split(',');
        bool IsAllNull = true;
        foreach(var i in propertyNames)
        {
            var p = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(i);
            var val = p.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
            if(val != null && val.ToString().Trim() != "")
            {
                IsAllNull = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(IsAllNull)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rules = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName),
            ValidationType = "atleastonerequired"
        };
        rules.ValidationParameters["otherpropertynames"] = OtherPropertyNames;
        yield return rules;
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
$(function() {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("atleastonerequired", "otherpropertynames");
    $.validator.addMethod("atleastonerequired", function (value, element, params) {
        var param = params.toString().split(',');
        var IsAllNull = true;
        $.each(param, function (i, val) {
            var valueOfItem = $('#Activity_' + val).val().trim();
            if (valueOfItem != '') {
                IsAllNull = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (IsAllNull) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    })
})
```

View - Edit & Create Forms are identical:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Activity", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "editActivityForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form activity-form">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Activity.RecordId)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Activity.Acres, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Activity.Acres, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Activity.Acres, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Activity.Volume, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Activity.Volume, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Activity.Volume, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Activity.Feet, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Activity.Feet, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Activity.Feet, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Activity.Hours, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Activity.Hours, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Activity.Hours, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Activity.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Activity.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Activity.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#editActivityForm'));" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Model with attirbute added:

```
    [AtLeastOneRequired("Acres,Volume,Feet,Hours", ErrorMessage = "Activity requires at least one measure - Acres, Volume, Feet or Hours.")]
    public Nullable<int> Acres { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Volume { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Feet { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Hours { get; set; }
```

Comment: I'm happy to add clarification or more info.  I'm not sure what more to add.  I can paste in all the code, but the code is the same for both forms, so not sure how that would help.  What do you need form me, to help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the client code.  I finally found the client code was not being hit.  I eventually found it was because the validation add was inside (function() {}).  I deleted that 'ready' piece and now it works every time.